# Alarm manager or sound notification are not working in release mode Android 13

Tags: android, flutter, android-alarms, ringtone

I've built an application that may notify a user after some period in time.
By "notify" I mean to play a sound using `flutter_ringtone_player` plugin.
The `android_alarm_manager_plus` is used to schedule a notification.

The problem is that it has stopped to work (to make a sound) after some moment in time.
I suppose it is because of Flutter version upgrade or Android 13 version installed on the phone.

The `oneShot` method duration is from 30 to 300 seconds I have tried.

Here is code I'm using to schedule method execution:

```dart
    var dr = Duration(seconds: config.delay);
    await saveShared(config);
    _scheduled = await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(dr, helloAlarmID, playAlarm,
        exact: true, wakeup: true, alarmClock: true, allowWhileIdle: true);
    return _scheduled;
```

`playAlarm` method implemented as below

```dart
  static void playAlarm() async {
    var config = await loadShared();
    playImpl(config)
        .then((_) => _scheduled = false)
        .onError((error, stackTrace) {
      print("failed to play notification");
      print(error);
      return true;
    });
  }
```

The whole [NotifyModel class is here](https://github.com/oleksabor/work-tracker/blob/master/lib/classes/notify_model.dart) used to schedule and play notification.
The [AndroidManifest](https://github.com/oleksabor/work-tracker/blob/master/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) file.

The same code is working on

- emulator `API 29`
- emulator `API 33`
- Pixel 4a phone (Android 13) in debug mode from VSCode

The problem is that it fails to work when built as release and installed from GooglePlay on the same Pixel 4a phone that is used to debug.

I do not have any plugin registration call in the `playAlarm` or `playImpl` method implementation.

The `playImpl(ConfigNotify? config)` method is called from both AlarmManager and UI button click. Both `FlutterRingtonePlayer.play` and `FlutterRingtonePlayer.playNotification` are working properly when called form UI.

What should I check to understand the reason of the difference between debug and release application on Android 13?

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.1, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 5.15.0-48-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
```

#### upd

I've just found [the similar issue](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/1077) however can't get it working yet using Flutter 3.0.5

Answer (score 2):

The `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` annotation has to be applied to the callback function when using Flutter 3.3 and Alarm manager Plus 2.0.7